# Unexpected end of regular expression using python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, mysql-python

I am trying to scrape stock prices from Yahoo! Finance into a local database as per a tutorial by [Chris Reeves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mi9IAlqSwbE), and I keep getting the above error when trying to execute this code. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? Thanks.

```
from threading import Thread
import urllib
import re
import MySQLdb

gmap = {}

def th(ur):
    base = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ur
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_'+ur.lower()+'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen(base).read()
    results = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    try:
        gmap[ur] = results[0]
    except:
        print "Got an error"

symbolslist = open("multithread/stocks.txt").read()
symbolslist = symbolslist.replace(" ","").split(",")

print symbolslist

threadlist = []

for u in symbolslist:
    t = Thread(target=th,args=(u,))
    t.start()
    threadlist.append(t)

for b in threadlist:
    b.join()
```

This is the exact error that I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "multithread/threads.py", line 11, in th
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

Comment: I preume that the error happens at `regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_'+ur.lower()+'">(.+?)</span>'`?

Comment: Sigh. Usual warning about parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: You'd need to share the full regex or at least the value of `ur.lower()` at the time the regex is constructed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sigh not. ;-) All these HTML regex questions serve to give people a better appreciation of regex, if not HTML.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I'm not sure if that's it, because if I comment out the code beyond "Got an error", it runs and when I execute the function th("AAPL") and th("GOOG"), and call gmap, it returns {'GOOG': '1,080.76', 'AAPL': '568.69'}.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, you didn't show us the important part.  That is, print `symbolslist`.  *Something* in that list is creating an invalid regular expression when you paste it into the `<span ...` boilerplate.

You can probably fix it by changing that line like so:

```
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + re.escape(ur.lower()) + '">(.+?)</span>'
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^          ^
```

However, if that works, it would probably only be hiding the real problem.  The real problem is probably that you have some kind of nonsense in `symbolslist`.